# Powershell [ Invoke-WebRequest] is it posible to make copy of Session from a certain point and then re-use session from the saved state?

Tags: powershell, session, request

Powershell [ Invoke-WebRequest] is it posible to make copy of Session from a certain point and then re-use session from the saved state?

I have no problem logging in and completing the full request.

The question is that I should perform hundreds of similar requests and to make a selection, for each parameter I send a separate post request (there are eight of post request) and I have to execute these requests sequentially.

the first four are identical for everyone, so, is it possible to save state of session after these four requests in copy of variable and then use it?

i tried to make copy of session using 
$sessionAfterBasicRequest=$session.PSObject.Copy()
but it's not working

maybe I'm missing basic things...

Answer (score 1):

I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do, but I think you want to maintain a single session for these many requests.

See [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6#code-try-5) for `Invoke-WebRequest`, explaining how to maintain the session foir a stateful web service when using `Invoke-WebRequest. I'll repeat the content below for posterity, since this example already explains what is going on:

```
$Body = @{
    User = 'jdoe'
    password = 'P@S$w0rd!'
}
$LoginResponse = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.contoso.com/login/' -SessionVariable 'Session' -Body $Body -Method 'POST'

$Session

$ProfileResponse = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.contoso.com/profile/' -WebSession $Session

$ProfileResponse
```

> The first call to `Invoke-WebRequest` sends a sign-in request. The command specifies a value of "Session" for the value of the `-SessionVariable` parameter, and saves the result in the `$LoginResponse` variable. When the command completes, the `$LoginResponse` variable contains an `BasicHtmlWebResponseObject` and the `$Session` variable contains a `WebRequestSession` object. This logs the user into the site.
>
> The call to `$Session` by itself shows the `WebRequestSession` object in the variable.
>
> The second call to `Invoke-WebRequest` fetches the user's profile which requires that the user be logged into the site. The session data stored in the `$Session` variable is used to provide session cookies to the site created during the login. The result is saved in the `$ProfileResponse` variable.
>
> The call to `$ProfileResponse` by itself shows the `BasicHtmlWebResponseObject` in the variable.